# GORM update array of associations

Tags: postgresql, go, associations, go-gorm, unique-constraint

I have an struct type `Stat` which has many-one associations with `Score`

```
type Stat struct {
    gorm.Model
    StatID  string `json:"id" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_stat"`
    Scores []Score `json:"scores"`
}
```

and Score is

```golang
type Score struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_score"`
    Score int `json:"score,string"`
    ScoreStatID uint `json:"score_stat_id" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_score"`
}
```

A stat won't change so it has a unique constraint on its stat ID (different from its index key). However the associated scores may/will change with time. I am running a cron job to retrieve the latest scores for the stat objects.

What I would like my code to do is update the `Score` objects associated with a `Stat` object each time, rather than create new ones. I though that a uniqueIndex on the `Score` fields (as you can see above) would handle this, but to no avail.

My latest attempt is to do this

```golang
    for _, v := range stats {
        if err := db.Where("stat_id = ? ", v.StatID).First(&v).Error; errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
            if err := db.Create(&v).Error; err != nil {
                return err
            }
            continue
        }

        if err := db.Model(&v).Updates(Stat{Scores: v.Scores}).Error; err != nil {
            fmt.Println("saving updated data failed", err)
        }
    }
```

i.e check/create the stat object and then attempt to update all the scores associated with it. However with these constraints I get the error

`ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_score" (SQLSTATE 23505)`

So when I attempt to do this without the constraint, I get duplicated entries within the table.

How can I update or create the array of associations without creating duplicated records and in effect just updating the score values to the new ones (if they have changed)?

EDIT:
I thought I had it with the following code:

```
    for _, v := range stats {
        tmpScores := v.Scores
        if err := db.Where("stat_id = ? ", v.ScoreID).Preload("Scores").First(&v).Error; errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
            if err := db.Create(&v).Error; err != nil {
                return err
            }
            continue
        }
        v.Scores = tmpScores
        if err := db.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Updates(&v).Error; err != nil {
            fmt.Println("saving updated data failed", err)
        }
    }
```

however this isn't quite right. The issue is if I do it this way, then the v.Scores are the values from the database, not the updated ones, so I save the scores into `tmpScores` and then reset them however that doesn't work because now the associated ID isn't correct on the association and it creates new entries...